# Problem in uploading image to server in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit

I'm facing problem while uploading image to the server. I have a upload url and I have to put the image to this url. I have tried so many times but getting Bad Request error.

This is my API Interface

```
interface APIInterface {
   @PUT
   fun uploadImage(@Url url:String,@Body image:RequestBody, @HeaderMap headers:HashMap<String,String>):Call<BaseResponse>
 }
```

This is my code for calling method

```
val requestBody = RequestBody.create(
        null,
        File(photoPath)

val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
    headers["Content-Type"] = "image/jpeg"
    headers["extension"] = "jpeg"
    headers["Authorization"] = token!!

val call=service.uploadImage(url,requestBody ,headers)
```

Comment: send the error you get

Comment: I will advice you use an api client to test if the problem is with the server or from your end

Comment: It is okay from server side as it's working fine on other platform.

Comment: please send your error message

Comment: I'm just getting Bad Request Error.

Comment: how the server is expecting your image ? as multipart?

Comment: It's expecting image buffer in body with PUT request.

Comment: Can you share the signature of your api?

Comment: Not possible. I have shared my code and details. Please suggest.

Comment: buddy how come I will know if your request is correct or not if I don't know the API signature, you are getting a bad request means your request you created is not understood by the server. so if it is not possible for you to provide the API signature it is not possible to know what is you are doing wrong.
You can remove the private info of your server details and all I just need to know the signature, means what server expect.

Comment: You need to call a PUT request to uploadUrl and send the image file to it in raw body. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we upload files/images in Multipart, hence this assumption.
so if your API is also expecting Multipart then you can do something like the below.

```
@Multipart
        @POST("/api/devices/{device_id}/image")
        Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(String device_id, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

You can create your bitmap from an image path like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePhotoPath);
```

You can create the multipart from your bitmap

```
   public static MultipartBody.Part getPhotoUploadRequestBody(Bitmap bitmap, int compressionQuality) {
    Log.d(TAG, "** getPhotoUploadRequestBody(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) Started ");

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressionQuality, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    bitmap.recycle();

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), byteArray);
    String name = "file"; //Server API expects this
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(name, name, requestBody);
    Log.d(TAG, "** MultipartBody.Part body created ");
    return body;
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this but using PUT instead of POST. But it return Bad Request Error.